# dnx web on ubuntu 14.04 throws "System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal" exception (1.0.0-beta8)

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, dnx

I am following various blog posts showing how to take an ASP.NET Core 1.0 application (formerly ASP.NET 5) and then install the correct .net core runtimes for Linux, so you can run on Linux, specifically on ubuntu 14.04 lts.

I have the .net core tools (dnvm and dnx) installed, and I have an ASP.NET application that is just the standard template application, and I have created a repository containing it, and am trying to run it on my Ubuntu system. The latest .Net and Visual Studio tooling on Windows is 1.0.0-beta8, and I have that also on my ubuntu box, which reports that Mono-x64-1.0.0-beta8-15858 is intalled.

I cloned my source code onto the ubuntu system and ran dnu restore, which succeeded.

From the folder containing project.json, I run `dnx web` and I get this:

```
Application startup exception: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal' from assembly 'System.Reflection.Metadata'.
  at System.Reflection.Internal.StreamMemoryBlockProvider.ReadMemoryBlockNoLock (System.IO.Stream stream, Boolean isFileStream, Int64 start, Int32 size) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Reflection.PortableExecutable.PEReader..ctor (System.IO.Stream peStream, PEStreamOptions options, Nullable`1 sizeOpt) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Reflection.PortableExecutable.PEReader..ctor (System.IO.Stream peStream, PEStreamOptions options) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ModuleMetadata.CreateFromStream (System.IO.Stream peStream, PEStreamOptions options) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Dnx.Compilation.CSharp.MetadataReferenceExtensions.CreateAssemblyMetadata (IMetadataFileReference fileReference) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Dnx.Compilation.CSharp.RoslynCompiler+<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<.ctor>b__1 (Microsoft.Dnx.Compilation.Caching.CacheContext ctx) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Dnx.Compilation.Caching.CacheExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass0_0`1[Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.AssemblyMetadata].<Get>b__0 (Microsoft.Dnx.Compilation.Caching.CacheContext ctx) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Dnx.Compilation.Caching.Cache.CreateEntry (System.Object k, System.Func`2 acquire) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Dnx.Compilation.Caching.Cache+<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<AddEntry>b__0 () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Lazy`1[Microsoft.Dnx.Compilation.Caching.Cache+CacheEntry].InitValue () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Is this indicating that there are conflicting versions of components or something is missing in my .dnx folder or that there is something wrong in my project source code?

At first I saw another weird exception, which I think had something to do with an "1.0.0-rc2" build of dnvm that was briefly visible on public servers today, then disappeared.

Some general setup steps:

1. Inspect ~/.config/NuGet/NuGet.Config, it should be like this:

.

```
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="AspNetVNext" value="https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetbeta8/api/v2/" />
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />
  </packageSources>
  <disabledPackageSources />
</configuration>
```

1. Make sure dnx and dnu and dnvm binaries are present and up to date. Make sure libuv exists and is the correct version.   Install runtimes if they are not present. (Check them with dnvm list, use dnvm install to install.)
2. Clone your sources.
3. Select a dnx version via dnvm use.
4. Make sure your user-account-level dnx runtime packages are restored via dnu restore.
5. ??What??
6. Go to folder containing project.json and run `dnx web`. Success?

Update: If I use dnvm use 1.0.0-beta8 on ubuntu 14.04, the dnx web runtime fault may be `Missing method AllocHGlobal in assembly /home/user/.dnx/runtimes/dnx-mono.1.0.0-beta8/bin/System.Reflection.Metadata.dll, type System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal` or it may be the System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshall in the title.

Update2: When I had the wrong contents in NuGet.Config, I was seeing some developer channel (internal unreleased) builds.

Current output of dnvm list:

```
me@mabox:~$ dnvm list

Active Version              Runtime Architecture OperatingSystem Alias
------ -------              ------- ------------ --------------- -----
       1.0.0-beta7          mono                 linux/osx
  *    1.0.0-beta8          mono                 linux/osx       default
```

Update 3: Once I installed coreclr target runtime type this issue went away. Once it's installed, dnvm list looks like this:

```
Active Version              Runtime Architecture OperatingSystem Alias
------ -------              ------- ------------ --------------- -----
  *    1.0.0-beta8          coreclr x64          linux
       1.0.0-beta8          mono                 linux/osx       default
```

Update 4: Both answers below contain essential information. One mistake I made was to assume that the ancient mono-2.x versions that are included in the apt-get repos of Ubuntu 14.04 are acceptable for DNX usage. They are not, instead as of the date I am writing this, only recent mono-2015.11.xx nightly builds are known to work.  At some point in future once a stable 4.3.0+ version is released, you would be using that, probably, with DNX, but I can't say for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The latest .Net and Visual Studio tooling on Windows is 1.0.0-beta8,
>   and I have that also on my ubuntu box, which reports that
>   Mono-x64-1.0.0-beta8-15858 is intalled.

To me it seems that you are not running against the same runtime.

Have you tried running a `dnvm upgrade` without targeting the nightly build server? It looks to me that your code might be using `beta8` assemblies on a `beta8-15858` runtime.

Run `dnu feeds list` on your Ubuntu box to make sure you are targeting the stable channel and not the developer one (should see only the default feed).

If you are targeting the wrong feed, you can change it from the `nuget.config` file located in your user folder under `~/.config/NuGet/Nuget.Config`.

Do the following to ensure you are on the proper runtime:

- Delete all existing runtimes in `~/.dnx/runtimes`
- `dnvm upgrade`
- `dnvm install -r coreclr latest`
- Then run `dnu restore` on your project
- `dnx web` should now work

Comment: You would need to talk to the ASP.NET team about that last point :P I'm sure that the aspnetvnext feed is not the right one. This is a nightly build.

Comment: Updated my answer to include the feed: https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetbeta8/api/v2 / https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetbeta8/api/v3/index.json

Comment: Have you tried running the CoreClr version instead of mono? CoreClr explicitly supports Ubuntu.

Comment: `dnvm install -r coreclr latest`

Comment: reformatted my answer to be more linear and easier to follow. less Wall-Of-Text

Comment: Weird fact: `dnu feeds list` works for me now, and didn't work ten minutes ago.  Installing coreclr runtime also seems to have changed the capabilities of dnu. I suspect that the `dnu` version for `mono` runtime in 1.0.0-beta8 is totally borked.  A version of dnu that doesn't have `dnu feeds list` is a good sign it's not a good dnu. nevertheless dnu reports its Type is "Mono" when I run `dnu --version`

Comment: You do not need those feeds.  beta8 has been released and is available from nuget.org.

Comment: @StaffordWilliams fixed.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to run beta8 against mono on ubuntu 14.04.  I just gave it a shot and was successful, here's the steps I followed;

1. Installed dnvm and libuv per the instructions [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Getting-Started-Prerequisites-for-Debian,-Ubuntu-and-derivitives).
2. Ran `dnvm install 1.0.0-beta8`
3. Installed [mono-snapshot-latest](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/ci-packages/) and executed `. mono-snapshot mono`
4. Cloned this new MVC 6 beta8 project `git clone https://github.com/staff0rd/TinyMvc -b beta8`
5. Ran `mozroots --import --sync` so [nuget doesn't throw TrustFailure](https://monomvc.wordpress.com/2012/03/06/nuget-on-mono/) exceptions
6. Executed `cd TinyMvc` and `dnu restore`
7. Run `dnx web`;

Result:

```
[mono-2015.11.13+00.47.00]root@8792d900344b:/TinyMvc# dnx web
Hosting environment: Production
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

Performed against an empty Ubuntu 14.04 from [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu/).

Comment: I was not using mono latest snapshot but rather the now ancient libmono-2.x that shipped with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.  After adding this repo to my apt sources and installing it, `mono --version` reports a much more respectable `Mono Jit compiler 3.2.8 (debian 3.2.8+....` - That certainly explains the low level startup failures. :-)

Comment: When I run `dnvm use 1.0.0-beta8` I still have to run `. mono-snapshot mono` or I will get a startup error (could not load file or assembly system.runtime). I guess that dnvm use can't take that requirement away. That command due to the dot syntax  (. mono-snapshot mono) is importing stuff into my bash session state, setting environment variables that mono needs, and perhaps updating paths, so that mono runtime environment core dlls are found?

Comment: It is instructive to point out to other "newbies" like me, that dnvm install does NOT install Mono itself, but rather some kind of Mono hooks and scaffolding, thus the instructions above.