# Can an ASP.NET 5 app communicate to MS SQL Server if it runs on Ubuntu?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, dnx

I created a new ASP.NET 5 web application using the new application wizard in Visual Studio 2015, code on bitbucket [here](https://bitbucket.org/wpostma/aspnetempty). After [a bit of trouble with dnvm runtime setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33675952/dnx-web-on-ubuntu-14-04-throws-system-runtime-interopservices-marshal-exceptio), I got the sources to run on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, well enough that the main static html page loads, while `dnx web` serves up my application. However if I click on the Register link, and try to put an email and password in I get "Error. An error occurred processing your request" on the web UI side, and on the dnx web side, I get this:

```
error   : [Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware] 
An unhandled exception has occurred: Could not load file or assembly 
'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. 
The system cannot find the file specified.
...
File name: 'System.Data.SqlClient'
   at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.LoadFromAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyName)
   at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.Resolve(IntPtr gchManagedAssemblyLoadContext, AssemblyName assemblyName)
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Storage.Internal.SqlServerConnection.CreateDbConnection()
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyRef`1.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at AspNetWebApplication.Controllers.AccountController.EnsureDatabaseCreated(ApplicationDbContext context)
   at AspNetWebApplication.Controllers.AccountController.<Register>d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActionExecutor.<CastToObject>d__8`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controllers.FilterActionInvoker.<InvokeActionFilterAsync>d__50.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controllers.FilterActionInvoker.<InvokeAsync>d__41.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Infrastructure.MvcRouteHandler.<RouteAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Routing.Template.TemplateRoute.<RouteAsync>d__27.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Routing.RouteCollection.<RouteAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Builder.RouterMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.<Invoke>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>d__5.MoveNext()
```

It appears that lazy initialization is occurring, and that the  System.Data.SqlClient class load fails.

The assembly exists in the "dnx cache" at `~/.dnx/packages/System.Data.SqlClient/4.0.0-beta-23409`.

I am assuming that the actual problem must be that the `System.Data.SqlClient` is not loading because it's actually not compatible with DNX and the Ubuntu `coreclr x64` runtime environment.  Alternatively perhaps I have to do something else to configure my app (a web.config or environment variable or something?). But in that case I would have expected the class to load, and fail to connect. I was kind of expecting it would try to find an MS SQL LocalDb instance just like it would try to find one on windows, but it doesn't, it just doesn't load, as if the .Net assembly itself was missing.

Update: It is interesting to look at packages like System.Text.Encoding. When NuGet fetches them, it has SEVEN, count-em SEVEN different actual DLLs in its package cache, by platform/os, each copy is in a different subfolder and those folders have these names:

```
DNXCore50      MonoTouch10  netcore50     xamarinmac20
MonoAndroid10  net46        xamarinios10
```

I believe that the System.Data.SqlClient, having not shipped any `netcoreXX` or `DNXCoreXX` variant folders in its nuget package, makes that package effectively non-portable though without any warning to users. So the class load failure is simply that NuGet has a package with that name, but it doesn't contain a variant folder that can be found and loaded by the coreclr x64 on ubuntu.

Comment: I would not expect it to work or try to work with localdb I would expect it to work talking to a ms sql database on Windows over a network

Comment: I believe that it will not actually work. But it would try (via entity framework's default connection determination logic) a connection string that tries localdb, should it get past the point of failing at class load time, or else EF7's default localdb behaviour would have to be conditional, something I would doubt.

Answer (score 3):

### Update 19 November

As of [ASP.NET 5 RC1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/11/18/announcing-asp-net-5-release-candidate-1.aspx) it should now be possible to use coreclr's System.Data.SqlClient on linux provided you have Multiple Active Result Sets turned off.  See the release notes on [Cross-platform SQL Client here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/11/18/announcing-asp-net-5-release-candidate-1.aspx).

---

It is possible to have ASP.NET 5 running linux communicate to MS MSQL, but perhaps not using the coreclr runtime.

`System.Data.SqlClient` was only flagged as *Done* on 14 October in [corefx](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx-progress/blob/master/src-diff/README.md), and beta8 was released October 15.  I'm unsure if it ended up being included in beta8 but the error you have posted is the same as that of beta7 which makes me believe the library is still not included.  Your investigations also seem to point at this.

If this is the case your only option to run it on linux is using the mono runtime (same as beta7).  To do this, remove the `"dnxcore50": { }` line from your project.json and tell `dnvm` to target mono rather than coreclr.  This then also requires mono (4.1 or later I think) to be installed on your linux box.

If you don't want to install mono on the box, a [mono-based aspnet 5 docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/aspnet/) is also an option.

Comment: I know it works on dnxcore50 on Windows with beta8 so I would expect it to work talking to ms sql over a network from a Linux machine but not with localdb as warren is trying I'm pretty sure that is Windows only

Comment: @Joe localdb (or any connection string for that matter) is irrelevant in this case considering System.Data.SqlClient cannot be found.  I just ran a test and saw that attempting to create an MSSQL connection on dnxcore50 works on windows, but throws the same exception as above on linux for both beta7 and beta8.

Comment: This is interesting because on ubuntu 14.04 the mono runtime in 1.0.0-beta8 appears totally broken as per this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33675952/dnx-web-on-ubuntu-14-04-throws-system-runtime-interopservices-marshal-exceptio

Comment: @WarrenP See my answer on that question

Comment: seems like a bug in the linux version of dnxcore50, hopefully it will be fixed in RC

Comment: The mono runtime was not broken in 1.0.0-beta8, it was that I never installed a modern Mono version, and was using the ancient mono-2.x version that shipped in Ubuntu 14.04 lts apt-get repos.